# Shall we allow 'tags' of living people?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is restricted to tags only. Recently I saw the tag named `[sadhguru-jaggi-vasudev]`.

Is it allowed to use the *names of people* as tags who do not have any well-known or publicly known lineage and are currently living?

---

**Context**:

There are *many* people across India and in other countries who are either teaching or participating in activities that are related to Hinduism. Some are more popular and some are less popular. Some obey scriptures and some other does not acknowledge them. Some cite from scriptures directly and some do not cite from scriptures. If we allow the names of people who are related to Hinduism, then there can be a significant increase in the number of tags which further attracts questions and answers that are irrelevant or less authentic. New users or some existing users of our main site also *may* start treating the people with their names as tags authentic and try to present the words of those people as answers even if those statements are entirely in contradiction with the core ideas and knowledge from scriptures. So, please share your opinions on it.

Comment: Yes we can have .. nothing wrong IMO ... as we can get many Qs related to them or to what they have said.

Comment: Having a tag does not mean we are endorsing them .. it's just a tag .. Guru Jaggi Vasudev  and his teachings are certainly related to Hinduism so nothing wrong IMO